# Search the entire array Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, search, filter

How to implement search on all three parameters? When doing a search for organisationName everything works as do all? Thank you very much!

```
func filterTableView(text:String) {


    dataArray = initialDataAry.filter({ (mod) -> Bool in

            return mod.organisationName
                .lowercased().contains(text.lowercased())
        })
        self.tableView.reloadData()


    if dataArray.count != 0 {

        dataArray = initialDataAry.filter({ (mod) -> Bool in

            return mod.tel1Org

                .lowercased().contains(text.lowercased())
        })
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

    if dataArray.count != 0 {

        dataArray = initialDataAry.filter({ (mod) -> Bool in
            return mod.tel2Org
                .lowercased().contains(text.lowercased())
        })
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check all three fields inside one filter:

```
func filterTableView(text:String) {
    let search = text.lowercased()
    dataArray = initialDataAry.filter({ (mod) -> Bool in
        return mod.organisationName.lowercased().contains(search) ||
               mod.tel1Org.lowercased().contains(search) ||
               mod.tel2Org.lowercased().contains(search)

    })

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use OR comparison on all the strings at once. This is same as adding all the strings and comparing the resultant string.

```
dataArray = initialDataAry.filter({ (mod) -> Bool in

            let searchString = mod.organisationName + mod.tel1Org + mod.tel2Org

            return searchString
                .lowercased().contains(text.lowercased())

        })
        self.tableView.reloadData()
```